# Add "file preview" to Document Library "forms"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, development, custom-form

In SharePoint 2013... (Enterprise).

On the Forms for my Document Library, I would like to add the "document preview" that comes up in Search Center (for Office and PDF files). Has anyone done this? I have thought of several ways. It seems like the easiest would be to add a web part to the default pages and then setup a connection to the SP item and build the "iframe" approriately (just like the Search Center does it). I am just not sure HOW to do it exactly. Any ideas?

Any "other" deas how to do this?

Comment: The easiest solution is using a Content Search webpart and set the search criteria to the document library. Then format the display template as per the requirement.

Comment: But how would I add that to the actual "EditForm" and "integrate" it? That is where I am having a brain freeze for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the WOPIFrame to help you with it.

To do that you probably have to do some custom coding the SP Designer itself.

But to understand more on WOPIFrame check out the following URL.
https://chrishattonnzlsp.wordpress.com/category/office-web-apps-server-2013/

Comment: Yes.. I have tinkered with that in the Search Center Results. I am just having a problem "getting started" on the "Forms". I am not sure where to begin, how to get access the "URL" of the document, if I should use JavaScript, or just a CSR JSLink for one of the fields (maybe the filename) or if I should just code and deploy dedicated pages via a Visual Studio Solution. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. Maybe it helps. I hope it works on-premises the same way as in Office 365:

[Add document preview to Document library form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/152774/add-document-preview-to-document-library-form/153041#153041)