# Preview document with metadata

Tags: document, metadata

I have a wish to add a new document to a document library. When the document is uploaded I want to have a preview of the document and the metadata at the same time.

Here is a pic of what I wish. Hope someone maybe have some similar requirement.

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same requirement, as viewing the document is really helpful for choosing the corresponding metadata...

Comment: Hi, yes here is a nice solutions - but you need Web Apps: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/152774/add-document-preview-to-document-library-form