# classic view - add a preview of the file like the Preview column in image library

Tags: sharepoint-online, preview

Is it possible to put a preview of the document (mostly word) in a library as an added column? like the preview/web preview column of the image library.

I am using the classic view in SharePoint online

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you can click on the dots beside a document and view a fully scrollable preview of the document in libraries.
[image]

In addition, you can refer to this post:
[Add document preview to Document library form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/152774/add-document-preview-to-document-library-form?rq=1)

Comment: 'as an added column' was the key word and the link you provided has a comment that says it does not work