# Document Preview and Search

Tags: sharepoint-addin, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem

In SharePoint 2010, there used to be a paid add-in that allowed you to preview documents (as in, you could mouse over a document in a library, and see it open, without downloading it). You could also search through the document library for a specific term, like "school", and the add-in would highlight the word "school" within the document in the preview pane.

That add-in no longer exists for SharePoint 2016, and it's parent company has gone under. It looks like you used to be able to do part of it (the preview pane) on your own with WOPIFrame, as shown here: [Add "file preview" to Document Library "forms"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126627/add-file-preview-to-document-library-forms), however, according to this same thread, this no longer works.

**Does anyone know of an add-in or possible custom solution for SharePoint 2016, that allows you to:**

1. Create a preview pane for a document by hovering over it in a document library.
2. Search within that document, from the preview pane, using the document library search.

**Thank you in advance. I appreciate your help.**

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't integrate Office Online Server for preview functionality? I know it doesn't meet the _exact_ requirement, but it is fairly close.

Comment: @TrevorSeward - Do you mean the preview you get in SP 2016 when you hover over the  ellipses icon in a Document Library?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @TrevorSeward - Understood. That won't quite do it, but I also understand such a product or method may not exist. Off the top of your head is there anything else you might recommend to accomplish this? Thanks by the way.

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of. I'm sure there is some JavaScript solution out there (I've seen them for PDFs) but that is going to be a bear to integrate.